# NFS mount using CHEF on LINUX | permissions of directory not getting changed

Tags: linux, unix, chef-infra

I am trying to do an NFS mount using CHEF. I have mounted it successfully. Please find the below code.

```
# Execute mount
node['chef_book']['mount_path'].each do |path_name|
  mount "/#{path_name['local']}" do
    device "10.34.56.1:/data"
    fstype 'nfs'
    options 'rw'
    retries 3
    retry_delay 30
    action %i[mount enable]
  end
end
```

i am able to successfully mount and make an entry in fstab file. But, after mounting the user:group for the mount linked is changing to root:root , which i was not expecting.

i want to use myuser:mygroup as owner:group. I tried changing the same using chown command but am getting permission denied issue

request some guidance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, this is not something Chef controls per se. After the mount, the folder will be owned by whatever the NFS server says. You can try to chmod the folder after mounting but that's up to your NFS configuration and whatnot as to if it will be allowed.

Comment: I do mount using CHEF after the folder is created by CHEF with myuser:myuser owner and group. But after mounting using CHEF it changes to root:root and am not able to do an chmod to the folder, for am getting "permission denied" error

Comment: Any permissions on the mount point folder before mounting are irrelevant, the mounted filesystem takes that over entirely. If a chmod after the mount fails, that is probably a policy set on your NFS server.

Comment: Got it... I tried it one more time and i find the mounted folder is color coded with blue text and green background , May i know what does that mean?

Comment: I don't even know what you mean by color coded. Guessing you mean in `ls`? In which case it's up to your ls colors config.

Comment: I had to take a different route. I delete my SMB mount and created a NFS mount ,then made it shared across different file share protocols. Seems to be working.